# Check if time is between two values - always return 0

Tags: android, time, android-calendar, datetime-comparison

I have a function to show an alert if time is between two values.

Eg:

start = 07:00:00

end = 17:00:00

```
assert start != null;
                        int from = Integer.valueOf(start.replace(":", ""));
                        assert end != null;
                        int to = Integer.valueOf(end.replace(":", ""));
                        Date date = new Date();
                        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                        c.setTime(date);
                        int t = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * 100 + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                        boolean isBetween = to > from && t >= from && t <= to || to < from && (t >= from || t <= to);
                        a = isBetween ? 1 : 0;

                        if(a == 1) { 
                           alert_f();
                           // a is never 1...
                        }
```

The problem is the `a` is never 1, even when the actual time is between the start and the end one.

any ideas why?

Comment: If your time strings also include the seconds shouldn't you also include the seconds from the calendar when calculating t?

Comment: @Luksprog thanks for your answer! How can I add seconds in my function? or remove from the start/end variables? can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

```
    String start = "07:00:00";
    String end = "17:00:00";
    LocalTime startTime = LocalTime.parse(start);
    LocalTime endTime = LocalTime.parse(end);

    LocalTime now = LocalTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Rome"));

    boolean isBetween = ! now.isBefore(startTime) && now.isBefore(endTime);
    int a = isBetween ? 1 : 0;
    System.out.println("Is between? " + isBetween + "; a = " + a);
```

When I ran it just now (17:15 in Rome) I got 0 like you, which is expected. If I specify a time zone where it’s not yet 5 PM I get:

> Is between? true; a = 1

So you need to pick the correct time zone for the code. If you trust the device time zone, you may use `ZoneId.systemDefault()`.

In my Boolean expression I am using “not before” to mean “equal to or after”.

I am exploiting the fact that your time strings are in ISO 8601 format, the format that `LocalTime` and other java.time classes parse (and also print) as their default. So we need no explicit formatter for parsing.

The date-time classes you were trying to use, `Date` and `Calendar`, are long outdated and poorly designed. Also integer values 70 000 and 170 000 don’t really make sense as representations of your start and end times. Instead I am using `LocalTime` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It’s a time of day without date and without UTC offset, so seems to be exactly what you need here.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, java.time works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can make use of SimpleDateFormat and get  the time, then simplify it to:

```
assert start != null;
int from = Integer.valueOf(start.replace(":", ""));
assert end != null;
int to = Integer.valueOf(end.replace(":", ""));
// here the change
int currentTime = Integer.valueOf(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date()).replace(":", ""));
boolean isBetween = to > from && currentTime >= from && currentTime <= to || to < from && (currentTime >= from || currentTime <= to);
// end
int a = isBetween ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this way

```
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
        Date from = parser.parse("2019-12-31 07:00");
        Date to = parser.parse("2019-12-21 17:00");
        int a;
        Date userDate = parser.parse(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").format(new Date()));
        if (userDate.after(from) && userDate.before(to)) 
            a = 1;
         else
            a = 0;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // Invalid date was entered
    }
```

Comment: It's not guaranteed that the times will be in the same day, for example, if the start time is 17:00 and end time is 7:00, comparing them considering it's the same day will not work. I presumed this checking his between condition checking if from is greater than to.